# How to collect mongodb::Cursor into a Vec in rust

Tags: mongodb, rust, async-await, database-cursor

I'm trying to use the `.find()` method in mongodb. The output yeilds a `mongodb::Cursor`. I'm unable to convert the cursor into a vector so that I can wrap them in a json and send it to my front-end. This is the following idea I've tried

[image]

The following error message is:

```
the trait bound `Vec<user_model::User>: Extend<Result<user_model::User, mongodb::error::Error>>` is not satisfied\nthe following other types implement trait `Extend<A>`
```

I've already included and `use futures::StreamExt;` and `use futures::TryFutureExt;` and tried out `.try_next()` and `.map()` instead of `.collect()`, still cant parse it

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Sorry I'll be aware of this next time. I thought the types provided by rust-analyzer would help others to understand what is happening

Comment: If you think the types could be helpful, provide a reproducible example. This is going the helo us understand the problem better. At least, provide the code in addition to the image.

Comment: yeah I'll make sure to adhere to the criteria from the next time onwards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting an element in the cursor to a `User` might fail. You may only collect into a `Vec` of `Result` with `.collect()`.

```
let serial: Vec<Result<User, _>> = users.collect().await;
```

The easy way to get to `Vec<User>` here would be to use `.try_collect()`. Just make sure to handle the `Err` correctly and not just use `unwrap` as I've done here.

```
let serial: Vec<User> = users.try_collect().await.unwrap();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've just started learning Rust. Hopefully I get good at it soon <3

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I managed this in one of my projects.
I simply iterate over the cursor calling `next` and push each item in a vector. I used the Document type to collect the results.
Using a match for each result allows to handle the errors properly, because extraction may fail.

```rs
let mut results: Vec<Document> = Vec::new();

while let Some(result) = cursor.next().await {
    match result {
        Ok(document) => {
            results.push(document);
        }
        _ => {
            return HttpResponse::InternalServerError().finish();
        }
    }
}
```